# How to parse this json result without making class in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

How can i parse this json without class in c#. I don't know what to use either an array or anything else.

This is the json result i want to be parsed

```
{
    "success": true,
    "status": 200,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "response": {
        "message": "Device Registered",
        "data": [
            {
                "ID": "607dbb9e08b4c22a",
                "Type_ID": "657911C6-AFA5-4AC4-922F-39E56CCB28CC",
                "Name": "Genymotion Google Nexus 5X",
                "Active": "1",
                "Insert_User": "Default",
                "Insert_Date": "2019-10-18 16:33:01.650",
                "Update_User": "Default",
                "Update_Date": "2019-10-18 16:33:01.650"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use linq-to-json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: Read about `JObject`. That's what you need. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: If you just need one value, do as suggested, if you are trying to save time and code, then just deserialize it to a concrete class (to actually save time and code for-reals)

Comment: I agree with @TheGeneral, generate class for your JSON data. It will take 5 minutes, but will save you lot of time in future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thx everyone, i just figure it out my self.
This is what i do.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public async Task<string> CheckDevice(string id)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constant.CheckDevicesRegistration + "id=" + id, string.Empty));

            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var jsonData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

                    var message = jsonData["response"]["message"].Value<string>();

                    resultService = message;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                resultService = "Connection-Error";
            }
            return resultService;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) instead of creating an object. But dynamic object cost more source than a normal class. If you have performance concern I don't recommend you; if not here you go:

```
  string json = @"[
  {
    'Title': 'Json.NET is awesome!',
    'Author': {
      'Name': 'James Newton-King',
      'Twitter': '@JamesNK',
      'Picture': '/jamesnk.png'
    },
    'Date': '2013-01-23T19:30:00',
    'BodyHtml': '&lt;h3&gt;Title!&lt;/h3&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;Content!&lt;/p&gt;'
  }
]";

dynamic blogPosts = JArray.Parse(json);

dynamic blogPost = blogPosts[0];

string title = blogPost.Title;

Console.WriteLine(title);
// Json.NET is awesome!

string author = blogPost.Author.Name;

Console.WriteLine(author);
// James Newton-King

DateTime postDate = blogPost.Date;

Console.WriteLine(postDate);
// 23/01/2013 7:30:00 p.m.
```

For more documantation have a look [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You can use use JObject to parse json

```
    dynamic response = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
    success   = response ?.success;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Json.NET**
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

**Documentation is here**

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

**Short explanation:**

For **Serialize**(object to string):

```
string text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
```

For **Deserialize**(string to object)

```
var jsonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
```

If you want to **Deserialize Anonymous type**, you can use this documentation, it's quite simple

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm